# Backspace wrong behaviour in textarea

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I've recently found this problem: when I press the backspace on the keyboard in a textarea component (inside a tabnavigator) , it doesn't delete the carachters but it goes back on the previous tab as if I pressed the back button of the browser.
This happens only with IE 11 and Flex SDK 3.6

```
<mx:TabNavigator id="tabNavigator" tabWidth="150" tabHeight="60" height="100%">
    <mx:VBox label="left">
        <mx:TextArea id="id1" maxChars="1000" width="75%"/>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox label="right">
        <mx:TextArea id="id2" maxChars="1000" width="75%"/>
    </mx:VBox>
    <mx:VBox label="top">
        <mx:TextArea id="id3" maxChars="1000" width="75%"/>
    </mx:VBox>
</mx:TabNavigator>
```

Comment: Are you sure the focus was correctly set to the textarea component ? It is strange that behavior only append With IE, since we are talking about flash. Have you tried with different browsers ?

Comment: Yes, sure of the focus and I tried with different browsers and different versions of IE

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and this script in the html template works for me:
(Prevent the backspace key, and set the focus to the flash, to delete the text)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function killBackSpace(e){
        e = e? e : window.event;
        var t = e.target? e.target : e.srcElement? e.srcElement : null;
        if(t && t.tagName && (t.type && /(password)|(text)|(file)/.test(t.type.toLowerCase())) || t.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'textarea')
            return true;
        var k = e.keyCode? e.keyCode : e.which? e.which : null;
        if (k == 8){
            if (e.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
                document.${swf}.focus();
            }
            return false;
        };
        return true;
    };
    if(typeof document.addEventListener!='undefined')
        document.addEventListener('keydown', killBackSpace, false);
    else if(typeof document.attachEvent!='undefined')
        document.attachEvent('onkeydown', killBackSpace);
    else
    {
        if(document.onkeydown!=null){
            var oldOnkeydown=document.onkeydown;
            document.onkeydown=function(e){
                oldOnkeydown(e);
                killBackSpace(e);
            };
        }
        else
            document.onkeydown=killBackSpace;
    }
</script>
```

http://dev.ektron.com/forum.aspx?g=posts&t=19188

Comment: Thanks for your help, but I found another way to solve thsi problem: you have to set to false the property historyManagementEnabled of the TabNavigator component